# Will XmlSerializer always output the same string for 2 different objects of the same arbitrary type with the same values?

Tags: c#, xml, string, serialization

I'm comparing 2 objects (of any, but both the same, type) by serializing them both to xml and comparing the strings using .NET's XmlSerializer class. Assuming that all values for each property are the same in both objects, are the output strings guaranteed to be the same? Or is there a chance that the order of properties isn't always the same (for the same object type, being serialized at about the same time) in the output?

In other words, could the outputs end up like this:
`"...<SomeProperty>1</SomeProperty><OtherProperty>abc</OtherProperty>..."`
and
`"...<OtherProperty>abc</OtherProperty><SomeProperty>1</SomeProperty>..."`

I know that attributes can be used to specify exactly what order to serialize properties in, but because this comparison is being done on 2 objects of (the same) arbitrary type, these attributes probably won't be there.

I assume the output format would be consistent for any given type, even if not predictable or controlled by explicit ordering attributes, but I can't seem to find any official confirmation in the class documentation.

Comment: XML is orderless by definition, so I would not assume that the XmlSerializer _always_ outputs properties in the same order.  You could also run into differences in whitespace. I would choose a different method of comparing two generic objects.

Comment: @DStanley - it's not so simple. XML tools do support things like document-order at various levels. More important here is whether a serializer could be non-deterministic in this respect. Theroretically possible but hard to imagine in reality.

Answer (score 2):

I use this trick in DataContractSerializer during unit testing, and haven't yet found a situation where it isn't the same order, although in theory it could well emit in a different order, I have never seen it in practise.